# What is the difference between these data frame assignments?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like so:

> ```
>  pid tid      pname 
>  2   NA       proc/boot/procnto-smp-instr
> ```

Now if I do this, I expect nothing to happen:

> y[c(FALSE), "pid"] <- 10

And nothing happens (`y` did not change). However, if I do this:

> y[c(FALSE), ]$pid <- 10

I get:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "pid", value = 10) :
>     replacement
>   has 1 rows, data has 0

So my question is, what's the difference between `[, "col"]<-` and `$col<-`? Why does one throw an exception? And bonus: where in the docs can I read more about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the code of `$<-.data.frame` which checks if the original data.frame is at least as many rows as the length of the replacement vector:

```
 nrows <- .row_names_info(x, 2L)
    if (!is.null(value)) {
        N <- NROW(value)
        if (N > nrows) 
            stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
                "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), 
                domain = NA)
```

`[<-` is a different function, which does not perform this check. It is a `primitive` function, which you can read more about in the [R Internals manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html)

Answer (score 1):

For once, these operations are performed by two very different functions:
`y[FALSE, 'pid'] <- 10` is the call to the `[<-.data.frame` function,  while
`y[FALSE, ]$pid <- 10` is the call to the `$<-.data.frame` function, the error message gives you this clue. Just how different they are you can see by typing their names (with back quotes, just like above). In this particular case, though, they intended to behave the same way. And they normally do. Try `y[1, 'pid'] <- 1:3` vs `y[1, ]$pid <- 1:3`. Your case is "special" as `y[FALSE, ]` returns you a "strange" object - a data.frame with 0 rows and three columns. IMHO, throwing exception is a correct behavior, and this is a minor bug in the `[<-.data.frame` function, but language developers's opinion on this subject is more important. If you want to see yourself where the difference is, type `debug([<-.data.frame)` and run your example. 
The answer to your "bonus" question is to type `?[<-.data.frame` and read, though it is very, very dry :(. Best.

PS. Formatting strips backticks, so, for instance, `[<-.data.frame` meant to be . Sorry.

Comment: It's so strange that these two functions part of the standard libraries disagree on what the correct behaviour is... I think the `[<-.data.frame` behaviour is more intuitive because if y was bigger and I had sometimes `y[c(T, T, F, T), ]$pid <- 3`, and sometimes `y[c(F, F, F, F), ]$pid <- 3`, then I'd expect the second one to just do nothing (I'm basically just telling R "assign 3 to pid of all rows that match these conditions" and my conditions are all false, so I want it to assign nothing.

Comment: The safe way to assign the same value to the entire column is ``y[, 'pid'] <- rep(10, nrow(y))``